# knife under pillow after mikveh?

Tags: minhag, mikvah-ritual-bath, evening-night, zohar

My sister told me her Rebbetzin had a minhag: If after going to the mikveh she did not have relations with her husband that night, she should sleep with a knife under her pillow to fight the evil spirits that are empowered by the absence of marital relations after purification.

Does anyone have a source for this and is this situation related to *Tehom Raba*, the great abyss which opens up when "renewing the Torah w/o sufficient knowledge" (which I believe includes blessings in vain) (Zohar 68, 69 [1](https://books.google.com/books?id=AXuv2wKr4NoC&lpg=PA222&vq=abyss&dq=zohar%20abyss%20blessing%20in%20vain&pg=PA221#v=snippet&q=abyss&f=false)) in which Lilith and her demons slay hundreds of thousands in the empty firmaments?

> 68. However, if one were to claim that the renovation of the Torah by one who does not even know what he is saying creates a firmament, then
>       look at one who is not familiar with the secrets of the Torah: since
>       he renews the Torah without having sufficient knowledge, all that he
>       renews ascends, and the reverse side of man (male part of the impure
>       force), and the false tongue (from Nukva of the impure force, called
>       Tehom Raba – great abyss) comes toward him. This reversed man skips
>       500 Parsaot (measures of distance) to receive this renewal of the
>       Torah, takes it and makes a false firmament out of it, called Tohu
>       (abyss).
> 69. And this reverse man then flies across the empty firmament, traversing 6,000 Parsaot in one bound. And as soon as this empty
>       firmament stops, an impure woman emerges at once, seizes onto this
>       empty firmament, and partakes in it. She leaves it and slays hundreds
>       of thousands, for as long as she remains in this firmament, she has
>       the authority and power to fly and traverse the whole world in an
>       instant.

Comment: I believe this custom is regarding someone who's husband is away and there is a safek Wether the husband may come home and she used the mikvah

Comment: I am assuming she is lubavitch

Comment: I do not know whether she is lubavitch, but will ask my sister.

Comment: The source can be found in Sefer Tahara Kihalacha perek 21,will write an answer soon hopefully

Comment: I hope it's sheathed.

Answer (score 5):

This is sourced in the Sefer Tahara K'halacha which brings that if a a woman is waiting for her husband who is out of town but does not know when he will return should be tovel so she will be mutar to him whenever he arrives. However, he brings segulos that the woman should perform to prevent any danger. This includes a knife under her pillow,or cover herself with a beged of her husband until he returns(see Ben Ish Chai which is mesupak if it is needed all nights or just the night of immersion).

**Sefer Tahara K'halacha :**

[image]

**This footnote brings all the sources for this idea:**

[image]

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3429

Comment: Sry,this is the best I could do,I don't know how to do all the fancy stuff

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Maybe someone else will do it, though....

Comment: I have np with that,wish I was more tech savvy